# React Modal - call function with params onClick, not on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

The issue I'm stuck on has to do with calling a function when a user clicks on a button, which will open a modal. The purpose of the function is to make a GET request for user information to populate the modal. I'm using the react-modal package, which accepts an onAfterOpen prop. I know I can use this prop to call my function, but to make the GET request, I also need pass in an id to the request.

My modal is set up as follows:

```
  <Modal
     isOpen={this.props.isSelected}
     onRequestClose={this.props.closeModal}
     onAfterOpen={this.props.getInfo(id)}
     // Also tried declaring function like below, but then I have no reference to user id.
     onAfterOpen={this.props.getInfo}
     contentLabel="Hello"
  >
  </Modal>
```

Issue with declaring my function like this is that my page renders a list of buttons, which is tied to a modal. So on render, this.props.getInfo(id) will be called.

For example, my container component will render a list of Button Components (say 9), and if each Button component contains a Modal component, then the function will get called 9 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this :

```
onAfterOpen={this.props.getInfo.bind(this, id)}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `onAfterOpen={(id)=>this.props.getInfo(id)}` work too ?

Comment: Thanks for that! I ended up using Nathan's suggestion, worked like a charm! Is there a difference from writing it: like (id)=>this.props.getInfo(id) vs ()=>this.props.getInfo(id)?

Comment: I wouldn't think Nathan's suggestion would work.  When the function is called which is set to onAfterOpen, it probably isn't passed the id argument automatically?